# remove random text from file name

Tags: powershell, rename

I have a folder full of files which have had some text prepended to the filenames.  For example:

`program1.m` has become `John Smith 23423_file_program1.m`.
`program2.m` has become `Jane Doe 235_file_program2.m`.

The number of characters that have been prepended is not consistent, but the substring `file_` is always the final set of characters I wish to remove.  Is there anyway to remove all characters up to and including the `file_` in a folder full of files?  This was my attempt, but as expect the `*` does not work in this scenario:

```psh
get-childitem *.m | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("*file_","") }
```

Comment: Won't help answer your question, but since you mention being new to PowerShell, I highly recommend the [Microsoft Academy JumpStart course](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/advanced-tools-scripting-with-powershell-3-0-jump-start)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. There are other ways to do this as well so don't be surprised if you find another one.

```psh
get-childitem *.m  -Filter *.m | ForEach{
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name -replace ".*file_")
}
```

Or shorter

```psh
get-childitem -Filter *.m | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace ".*file_"}
```

You had the right idea but the issue you have is the string `.replace()` method is looking to match static strings and does not use wildcards. The way you had it it expected an asterisks to appear in the string which one did not.

Instead we use `-replace` which supports regex. `.*file_` would satisfy the requirement of *remov[ing] all characters up to and including the _file*. Since you just want it removed we don't offer a replacement string.

If regex is not your friend you should try and warm up to him. If not some old school methods work just as well.

```psh
$file = "blah_file_program.m"
$file.Substring($file.LastIndexOf("_") + 1)

program.m
```

Comment: @SWJ As opposed to first-borns, we usually prefer an upvote and accepted answer around here.